# How does this implementation of swap works in Python?

Tags: python, swap

```
def fibonacci(num):
    a=0
    b=1
    for i in range(num):
        a, b=b, a+b
    print a
```

How does the line inside the loop works?
Somehow a & b 's values change, can seems to understand how..

EDIT:
For some reason I got confused, thought that the middle exp of b=b is something new... 
didn't read it well.. 
It really is (a,b) = (b, a+b) which is the basic form of swap in python (:

Comment: [Read the first point](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)

Comment: `a,b = b,a ` is a straight forward swap in python likewise you could do `a,b=2,1` to assign 2 to a and 1 to b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b, a+b` creates a tuple

This tuple is unpacked back into `a` and `b`

Answer (score 2):

This line `a, b = b, a+b` is equivalent to `(a, b) = (b, a+b)`, which is a tuple assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The line in question can be more clearly written (through tuple packing on the right side and sequence unpacking on the left side) as:

```
(a, b) = (b, a + b)
```

As the assignments to a and b are carried out in parallel, this is exactly the same as:

```
new_a = b
new_b = a + b
a     = new_a
b     = new_b
```